# MySQL query: search multiple strings in a single field, from CSV in other field/table?

Tags: mysql, regex, search

I have a table that contains two TEXT fields with textual content, and in a separate table, a field that contains comma separate values of keywords that can be more than one word. The following query works in my WAMP using Appserv, does not works in our Hostgator LAMP...why??

```
SELECT 
    t.content_me, t.content_visitor, t.Id, exp.owner_user_id, exp.name
FROM (SELECT t.content_me, t.content_visitor
      FROM `texts` AS t 
      WHERE t.owner_user_id=1 *<== obviously this changes...*
      ORDER BY t.Id DESC) AS t 
INNER JOIN exp ON t.Id = exp.owner_user_id AND 
      t.content_me REGEXP (REPLACE(exp.keywords,',','|')) 
WHERE t.owner_user_id=e.owner_user_id=6 
ORDER BY t.Id DESC
```

Furthermore, if I literally put a value in this part:

```
t.content_me REGEXP (REPLACE(exp.keywords,',','|'))
```

as lets say:

```
t.content_me REGEXP ('yeah|ok')
```

It works in Hostgator. So I guess the problem is that REGEXP (REPLACE(exp.keywords,',','|')) thingy...right?

EDIT

Ok, I simplified the query just for the fun of it :)

```
SELECT 
    t.Id,  t.text,  t.owner_user_id FROM `t` 
LEFT JOIN e ON e.owner_user_id = t.owner_user_id 
WHERE  
    t.text REGEXP REPLACE(e.keywords,',','|') AND t.owner_user_id=1
```

Same results: works in WAMP, doesn't in LAMP. Also if I do literal REGEXP like

```
REGEXP REPLACE('yeah,can',',','|')
```

Works in both servers. My guess is that something is happening with

```
REGEXP REPLACE(e.keywords,',','|')
```

i.e, having the REGEXP use field content and not literal sting.

EDIT:

Well...now I see the LAMP MySQL throws an error (not happening in WAMP):

*Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation 'regexp'*

So....

```
 REGEXP REPLACE(e.keywords,',','|') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

Fixed it

Comment: A couple of issues/questions: You are using the same table alias twice. Why use a select in the from? If you add the _REPLACE..._ to the column list, what does it display? Is it a valid regex?

Comment: The `ORDER BY` in the subquery is probably ignored.  Why do you have it?

Comment: It is confusing to use `t` as two different aliases; please make them different.

Comment: Ok, simplified the query, still the same: works in my local server, but doesn't in our hostgator account.